With Swagger UI and C# ASP.NET Core, is it possible to have verbatim string literals in the text of HTTP post body?
We have the following sample program in a controller of ASP.NET Core MVC, and we are testing by the Swagger UI.
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [HttpPost("TestArgs")]
    public IActionResult TestArgs(string argsOfStrings)
    {
        return Ok(argsOfStrings);
    }

    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [HttpPost("TestPostBody")]
    public IActionResult TestPostBody([FromBody] string bodyOfStrings)
    {
        return Ok(bodyOfStrings);
    }

The function TestArgs passes arguments as URI parameters, and in Swagger UI:

For input text, the function returns text.
For input "quoted text", the function returns "quoted text" literally.

However, the function TestPostBody uses [FromBody] and the behavior gets more complicated in Swagger UI in our test:

For input "quoted text", the function returns quoted text, so the " characters are gone. The cURL command is:

curl -X 'POST' \
   'https://localhost:7138/path/to/TestPostBody' \
   -H 'accept: */*' \
   -H 'Authorization:  ... ' \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -d '"quoted text"'


For input text, the cURL command has -d 'text' and function gets the following error.


Error: response status is 400
Response body
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"errors": {
"$": [
"'text' is an invalid JSON literal. Expected the literal 'true'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
],
"bodyOfStrings": [
"The bodyOfStrings field is required."
]
},
"traceId": " ... "
}

With the above program and Swagger UI, we wonder whether it is possible to have something like Verbatim String Literals. And we hope to make the input fathfully transmits the post body to the function, e.g. "quoted text" gets to "quoted text" keeping the quote characters, and hopefully we do not need to use escapes like "\"quoted text\"".

Could you try In the "Request body" section, change the Content-Type from application/json to text/plain.

In my humble opinion, what we are concerning now is why we define [FromBody] string bodyOfStrings and we already set a string value like test string but it gives us 400 error as the response, but when we set a string value like "test string"(containing double quotes surrounded) will work well.
I think this is the expected behavior for asp.net core model binding. When we use this attribute, the ASP.NET Core runtime delegates the responsibility of reading the body to an input formatter. And I'm afraid the default content-type is application/json, see this section.

By default, ASP.NET Core includes JSON based input formatters for
handling JSON data.

Then for JSON, below are valid. If it's a JSON string, then "string" is valid but string is invalid. So that that's why I say this shall be the expected behavior.
{
    "string":"asdf",
    "int":123,
    "boolean":true,
    "null":null
}

By the way, I test with text/plain which doesn't work as well. We need to add text/plain input format to support it.
